# Annotating elements of arguments object in recursive function (Error TS2345)

Tags: typescript, types

I have a Typescript function that takes a variable number of arguments and accesses them via the [`arguments object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments):

```js
function foo(): string {
    const out: Array<string> = [];

    for (const arg of arguments) {

        const argType = typeof arg;

        if (argType === 'string' || argType === 'number') {
            out.push(arg.toString());
        } else if (Array.isArray(arg)) {
            if (arg.length) {
                const inner = foo.apply(null, arg);
                out.push(inner);
            }
        }
    }
    
    return out.join(' ');
}
```

The line `const inner = classNames.apply(null, arg);` shows the following error:

> TS2345: Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[]'.   Target allows only 0 element(s) but source may have more.

The error makes sense to me, but I have no idea how to fix / properly annotate it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is `classNames`?  Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/WPxdqW) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: @jcalz Absolutely, that was a typo, my bad. As it's a recursive function, `classNames` should haven been `foo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem by replacing the use of the [`arguments object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) by the following more explicit approach:

```js
type fooArguments = Array<number | string | fooArguments>;


function foo(...args: fooArguments): string {
    const out: Array<string> = [];

    for (const arg of args) {
        const argType = typeof arg;

        if (argType === 'string' || argType === 'number') {
            out.push(arg.toString());
        } else if (Array.isArray(arg)) {
            if (arg.length) {
                const inner = foo.apply(null, arg);
                out.push(inner);
            }
        }
    }

    return out.join(' ');
}
```

If there is a way, I'd still be interested in how to use the arguments object in typescript.